# Not having pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX in TexWorks

Tags: compiling, texworks

Because of some problems (like getting stuck while compiling) I deleted my miktex and reinstalled the last version from its website (`basic-miktex-20.11.x64.exe`). Then I downloaded **TextWorks** from [here](https://github.com/TeXworks/texworks/releases)(.zip file). It seems that this TexWorks is a portable version. Now when I start TexWork I only have separate processing tools of: `pdfLatex`, `BibTex`, `XeLatex`,... . But I need something like `pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX` That I had before. When I compile my file with only pdfLatex, my citations get like this `[?]` and not known. How can I enable these combined processing tools? (I don't have them in Edit/Preferences/typesetting/processing tools list too).

[image]

Comment: I have no idea how to configure texworks to make a combined pipeline but using the menu you show, simply choose pdflatex then bibtex then pdflatex again

Comment: @David Carlisle: Oh, thanks. Your help at least tide me over. I am really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to edit the option `pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX` you can click Edit-> settings.
Then the settings look like this:[image: Add a new programm(cross at the bottom right; Command is texify.exe; Arguments are '--pdf', --synctex=1, --clean and $fullname; also tick the show pdf afterwards, if you like)]

Add a new programm(cross at the bottom right; Command is `texify.exe`; Arguments are '--pdf', `--synctex=1`, `--clean` and `$fullname`; also tick the show pdf afterwards, if you like

Comment: Was it helpful? Then please mark as solved. Otherwise, whats questionable?

Comment: Very helpful! I installed a new version of TeXworks on a different machine, which didn't have the pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX option which I'm sure my older version must have come with!